# How to save Data to coreData

Tags: ios, core-data, model, nsmanagedobject

i have a problem with saving data with CoreData.

In my app iam scanning a barcode and show the barcode in an View.
On this View is a saveButton. I want to save the Data with coreData but my app crashes.

i get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Event''
```

---

I have worked out a lot of tutorials but it doesnt work. i cant include it to my project :(

Now i want to start it again.

Can someone help my at first to get working the savebutton step by step?

brush51

Comment: You'll need to include a little more code if anyone is going to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that link, and see if helps?! let me know if this is the right solution?!

[Core-Data iPhone: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632497/core-data-iphone-could-not-locate-an-nsmanagedobjectmodel)

Comment: thank you i have programmed a new project just to test save function.