# xcode ios : crashing after including coredata to old project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, core-data

I have a working project that Im  amending,

it crashes after trying to use coredata,

The project didnt have coredata before, so it was added,

as it was for a previous base sdk [number??], `applicationDocumentsDirectory` returns a NSString, and not a URL,

I have changed it to work?? but is crashing when attempting to use coredata,

```
#import "QRGenAppDelegate.h"

//#import "QRGenViewController.h"

#import "MainViewController.h"


@implementation QRGenAppDelegate


//@synthesize window; //viewController

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize navigationController = _navigationController;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [__managedObjectModel release];
    [__managedObjectContext release];
    [__persistentStoreCoordinator release];
    [_window release];
    [_navigationController release];

    //[viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    MainViewController *menuVC= [[[MainViewController alloc]init]autorelease];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:menuVC];

    //self.window.rootViewController = menuVC;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

    [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



    return YES;
}


//CD

//Explicitly write Core Data accessors
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }

    return __managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];

    return __managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }


    //mi solucto!!

    //NSURL *storeURL= [NSURL URLWithString:[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ClientOcci.sqlite"]];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db.sqlite" ofType:nil];

    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];

   // NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ClientOcci.sqlite"];
    //NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]    URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ChildCare_v02.sqlite"]; //actual SDK style for blank db

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {


        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
+ (NSString*)applicationDocumentsDirectory {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return documentsDirectory;
}
//CD 


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
}



@end
```

it crashes in:

```
__managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];

EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

so how I have tried in the project settings to make the base SDK 5.1 but still crashing,

why my project doesnt like the URL as return method?
how to fix it?
if I change this to a newer SDK will brake in other methods?

EDIT>>
I have tried suggestion of @ierror,

adding to my rootVC:

```
if (managedObjectContext == nil) { 
        managedObjectContext = [(QRGenAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
        NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  managedObjectContext);}
```

But now is crashing in the appDelegate,

in

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain]; // crashes here!!!

    return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

what to do?

thanks a lot!

Comment: A silly question, I know, but is there a valid model for the code to draw from (i.e. an xcdatamodeld file)? The face it's crashing when trying to merge the model bundles leads me to think there may be an issue there. Also, is the persistent store valid, by which I mean does calling `NSLog(@"store %@", __persistentStoreCoordinator);` right before it crashes give a non-nil value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this question on stack overflow

[Core data error iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963815/core-data-error-iphone/8967935#8967935)

It will resolve your issue

Comment: hi thanks, I tried your suggestion but still crashing, please see edit, thanks!

Comment: Did you try these instructions: http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2009/12/adding-core-data-existing-iphone-projects/