# Error in iPhone core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

My `AppDelegate.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Child.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, retain, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

`AppDelegate.m`:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (!context) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
    return YES;
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application { /* Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:. */
    NSError *error;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Handle the error.
        } 
    }
}
// Explicitly write Core Data accessors
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }
    return managedObjectContext;
}
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }
    managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    return managedObjectModel;
}
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"iSalahProject.sqlite"]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if(![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*Error for store creation should be handled in here*/
    }
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
@end
```

My controller implementation class where entity is being created and I am getting the error:

```
-(IBAction)addChildren:(id)sender{
    inputChildName = nameOfChild.text;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];
    Child * childrenName = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    childrenName.name = inputChildName;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Child''
```

I am using iOS-5 XCode 4.2 ARC. Please help me resolving this issue, I already have spent hours resolving it, but I couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: May I know that why my question has voted down and i think the person who has voted down my question, must have gotten the solution then please do update the answer too. Thanks

Comment: Your question would be greatly improved if you a) removed superfluous code, and b) explained what you've already tried. As you see, someone has already offered suggestions that aren't helpful because that information is lacking.

Comment: I think it is voted down because it is a bad question. You are not telling us what you have tried, and when people try to help, you are basically commanding them to 'give you the solution'. I doubt the people who voted this down bothered to find the solution.

Comment: downvotes without comments are complete useless. Fro me this question was useful, because the answer ist good. IMHO it is not so easy to track this bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application is terminating because your `managedObjectContext` is nil. Check for it and if its nil copy it from delegate. You can use this if condition in your `-(IBAction)addChildren:(id)sender` method

```
if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
{ 
    managedObjectContext = [(CoreDataBooksAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  managedObjectContext);
}
```

Comment: I hope this is the issue and this will solve your issue.. This is something you won't find in tutorials when you follow them..

Comment: @Paul.s:  Yes. I am sure thats the only mistake he is making. As I aslo faced same issue few days before when I started Core Data. If he had searched little bit more he would have saved his time by posting a question. I found solution from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632497/core-data-iphone-could-not-locate-an-nsmanagedobjectmodel

Answer (score 1):

Following are the possibilities for this error to occur:

- Typo in the Entity name.
- Nil managed object context object.
- Failure to add the model containing the entity to the persistent
  store the context uses.
- Failure to add the correct persistent store to the context itself.

Comment: Please tell me the solution, I have already checked all these.

Comment: I strongly doubt anyone will care to give you the solution when that's your attitude.

Comment: have you checked context at this line "NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];" ??
are you sure your context isn't null at his point?