# Cannot find NSManagedObjectModel for entity name

Tags: ios, core-data

I get the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not
>   locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'CorePlaylist''

But it worked a little while ago! Now I get the error before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is terminated.

My code is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSLog(@"DID finish launching %@", [self managedObjectContext]);

    PlaylistsViewController *table = [[PlaylistsViewController alloc] init];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (!context) {
        NSLog(@"\nCould not create *context for self");
    }

    table.context = context;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

EDIT:

```
-(void) getData {
context = [(ClientAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CorePlaylist" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setFetchBatchSize:20];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"playlistid" ascending:YES];

NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];

[request setSortDescriptors:newArray];

NSError *error;

NSMutableArray *results = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

[self setArr:results];

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This usually happens if you change your data model. If you changed it, just delete the app from the device and compile again. And if you changed the entity name, check if the one you use in code is still the same

Comment: I've already tried this and the error first started while I weren't working with coredata.

Comment: try to clean the project too.

Comment: Wait, `CorePlaylist` is not an Entry? It's the name of your Model?

Comment: Its the entity, the name of the model is Client ;) Delete the app, clean it and rebuild but still same error

Comment: But how can this error be there without using core data? This is a coreData error message which means there is no CoreData Model found with the Entity named `CorePlaylist`. May you also post a image of your Model and the code sniple where you try to catch the entity...

Comment: The coredata was working, then while I was coding in another class with no connection to the coredata it stopped working.

Comment: Hm, I am running out of ideas. Did you maybe change your project location or project name? Check in your AppDelegate if the right managedobjectModel is loaded...

Comment: Me too, it is the right MoM that is loaded. Thank you for your help anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your coreDataModel files are in the project and the entities your are calling are correctly spelled (case sensitive).

If you are testing on your device, you may need to completly remove the application they to deploy it again to prevent corrupted database issues.

Comment: I've already tried this and the error first started while I weren't working with coredata.

Comment: You may also try to re-generate your entities code using Xcode

Comment: Deleted my entities, deleted the app, cleaned and then re-added the entities but still the same problem :/

Comment: Are you sure your manageObjectContext is properly set before you call any entity? (ie. before your application has finished loading ?)

Comment: You can also try to locate the problem more precisely : `NSLog(@"Context: %@",context);
NSLog(@"PS Coord : %@",context.persistentStoreCoordinator);
NSLog(@"MOM : %@", context.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel);
NSLog(@"Entities : %@",[[context.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel entities] valueForKey:@"CorePlaylist"]);`  (cf. [This issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632497))