# Issue with Core Data in my app

Tags: ios, core-data

I am making a very simple app to learn the concept of Core Data. In this app, my goal is to show the list of people in a tableView.

I started with an Empty Application and I made sure Core Data and ARC were ticked. I also managed to create *.xcdatamodeld, *.storyboard and the *.h/m files to program the views/features.

In the app, if the user clicks `+` button on the navigationBar of `MainScreenViewController`, the app opens another viewController (`InputDetailsViewController`) lets the user enter name, phone number, email and tag. When the user clicks Save button, the app saves the data and displays the entered info on the table on previous viewController (`MainScreenViewController`).

In order to manage the data, I created two entities: `BasicInfo` and `DetailedInfo`. `BasicInfo` has two attributes: `name` and `phone` and relationship: `details` connected to destination `DetailedInfo`. Similarly, `DetailedInfo` has two attributes: `email` and `tag` and relationship: `basic` connected to `BasicInfo`. Once these attributes and relations were defined, I created `NSManagedObject` subclass for each entity.

I also managed to create the fields to enter information in the above mentioned attributes. But when I press the save button on `InputDetailsViewController`, I get the following message:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'BasicInfo''`

The relevant sections of my code are as follows:

InoutDetailsViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BasicInfo.h"
#import "DetailedInfo.h"

@interface InputDetailsViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phoneField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tagField;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;

- (IBAction)closeKeyboard;
- (IBAction)saveFields;
```

InputDetailsViewController.m:

```
#import "InputDetailsViewController.h"

@interface InputDetailsViewController ()
@end

@implementation InputDetailsViewController

@synthesize nameField, phoneField, emailField, tagField;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)closeKeyboard
{
    [nameField resignFirstResponder];
    [phoneField resignFirstResponder];
    [emailField resignFirstResponder];
    [tagField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)saveFields
{
    if (self.managedObjectContext == nil) {
    NSLog(@"NSManagedObjectContext is nil");
    }

    BasicInfo *basicInfo = (BasicInfo *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"BasicInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; //*
    DetailedInfo *detailedInfo = (DetailedInfo *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DetailedInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; //*

...
}
```

@end

`//*` is where the app throws an exception.

In order to find out where the problem is, I did the following:

1. I compared my code with the source code on raywenderlich's tutorials (http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started and the other 3 tutorials).
2. Checked if `managedObjectContext` was `nil` by any chance by using an `if ()` statement in `saveFields` method.
3. Made sure that the spellings are the same in xcdatamodeld and variables in files.

Beyond this, I do not know how to find the error or why does my app terminate abruptly.

I sincerely appreciate your input.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look inside the method -(NSManagedObjectModel*)managedObjectModel. Look for the line that starts with NSURL *modelURL = .... Does the name entered in URLForResource match your core data model name?

Comment: @ yeesterbunny: Yes it does. Would you like to take a look at the entire program if it helps?

Comment: Maybe later. Where is -(NSManagedObjectModel*)managedObjectModel? In your AppDelegate? How is your self.managedObjectContext in InputDetailsViewController assigned?

Comment: `-(NSManagedObjectModel*)managedObjectModel` is in `AppDelegate`. I did not get you last question.

Comment: I have not assigned `self.managedObjectContext` anywhere in `InputDetailsViewController`. I don't know if I have answered you question.

Comment: This is why you are getting the error. You need to assign self.managedObjectContext to the managedObjectContext in the AppDelegate. After you do, your error should go away.

Comment: I imported AppDelegate.h into the `InputDetailsViewController` and added the statement as suggested in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1640224/1560345 . It stopped crashing. is this how you wanted me to do it?

Comment: Exactly. Good job! Does your project work as intended now?

Comment: i will just go ahead and develop it further.. i was busy with something else for a few mins

Comment: pls give me a few mins, i'll +vely get back to you

Comment: Sure, it seems like my suggestions helped you solve your issue described in this question. I'll post my comment that helped in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment section:

This is why you are getting the error. You need to assign self.managedObjectContext to the managedObjectContext in the AppDelegate. After you do, your error should go away